# Xcode 9 has duplicated my Source Control account 12 times

Tags: xcode9

I have set up my Github account in Xcode 9 once, two or three days ago.  It works as I would expect.

Checking this morning, it now appears in the list of accounts 12 times!

Does anyone know how this is linked into the Keychain so I can check if I have duplicate entries there?

I was going to delete the duplicates but the following warning is displayed:  "Do you want to remove the password for the repository “ad-johnson” from the keychain?  This operation cannot be undone".

What I don't want to do is delete them and screw something up.  I'm already having other problems with Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by shift-clicking to select all but one of the duplicate accounts and then deleting. If you do this, you will see a confirmation dialog for each account before it is deleted. In my case, I had about twenty duplicates for a project that was only a couple of days old. After I deleted the last duplicate (leaving one account, as expected), my app successfully deployed to my phone.

I had the thought that perhaps something was causing the account to be duplicated with each deploy, but after performing the fix described above, I deployed several more times and only saw the same one original account.

Comment: I did the same in the end and nothing has been re-duplicated.